# Routing works on developement server(localhost), but doesn't in production build that's on a server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm getting everything quite ready and working on my developement server when I was trying to deploy to an actual webdisk, components aren't rendering at all.

There's nothing coming up on console, but the picArray state gets updated with the information coming from backend.

Basically what's happening can be seen on these images: 1st one (localhost / developement server) is rendering the Login component, and in the 2nd (uploaded to server) image Login component is not being rendered at all.

[image: localhost]
[image: server]

I have no idea what's going on here, so I've decided to look for some help. 
I've included the code of app.js, Login.js since it's the index. I also included my package.json.

What I've tried: I've tried building without Router basename, adding the exact address and path to package.json's "homepage" and trying a bit different syntax on the route paths.

app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import {getAllMedia} from './utils/MediaAPI';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Home from './views/Home';
import Profile from './views/Profile';
import Single from './views/Single';
import Login from './views/Login';
import {tokenCheck} from './utils/MediaAPI';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    picArray: [],
    user: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getAllMedia().then(pics => {
      this.setState({picArray: pics});
    });
    tokenCheck(localStorage.getItem('Login-token')).then(data => {
      if (data.message) {
        this.setState({errorMessage: data.message});
      } else {
        this.setState({user: data});
        this.setState({errorMessage: ''});
      }
    });
  }

  setUser = (data) => {
    this.setState({user: data});
    localStorage.setItem('Login-token', data.token);
    this.setState({errorMessage: ''});
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.setState({user: ''});
    localStorage.clear();
    tokenCheck(localStorage.getItem('Login-token')).then(data => {
      this.setState({errorMessage: data.message});
    });
    return <Redirect to='/'/>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div id='container'>
          <Router basename="/~juhoh/testbuild">
            {!this.state.errorMessage && <Nav/>}
            <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (
                <Login {...props} setUser={this.setUser}/>
            )}/>
            <Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => (
                <Home {...props} picArray={this.state.picArray}/>
            )}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile" render={(props) => (
                <Profile {...props} userData={this.state.user}/>
            )}/>
            <Route exact path="/single/:id" component={Single}/>
            <Route exact path="/logout" component={this.logout}/>
          </Router>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.object,
};

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {login, tokenCheck} from '../utils/MediaAPI';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {registerUser} from '../utils/MediaAPI';
import {checkIfUserNameExists} from '../utils/MediaAPI';

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
    full_name: '',
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    tokenCheck(localStorage.getItem('Login-token')).then(data => {
      if (data.message) {
        console.log('No token found. No redirection needed.');
      } else {
        this.props.history.push('/home');
      }
    });
  }

  handleInputChange = (evt) => {
    const target = evt.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    //console.log(name, value);
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  login = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then((user) => {
      if (user.token) {
        this.props.setUser(user);
        this.props.history.push('/home');
      } else {
        window.alert(user.message);
      }
    });
  };

  register = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    checkIfUserNameExists(this.state.username).then((isAvailable) => {
      if (isAvailable.available === true) {
        registerUser(this.state.username, this.state.password,
            this.state.full_name, this.state.email).then((data) => {
          if (data.error) {
            window.alert(data.message + '\n' + data.error);
          } else {
            this.login(evt);
            window.alert(data.message + '\nLogging in...');
          }
        });
      } else {
        window.alert('username not available');
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.login}>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"
                   value={this.state.username}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"
                   value={this.state.password}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>

          </form>
          <br/>

          <h1>Register</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.register}>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"
                   value={this.state.username}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"
                   value={this.state.password}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

            <br/>

            <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="fullname"
                   value={this.state.full_name}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"
                   value={this.state.email}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>

            <button type="submit">Register</button>

          </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setUser: PropTypes.func,
  history: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Login;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4"
  },
  "homepage": "."
}
```

Comment: What kind of server is your app hosted in? Node.js? Apache? Did you created your app with `create-react-app`? You forgot to specify those details in your question, otherwise we could give you a non-accurate answer.

Comment: Sorry about leaving out some details. It's created with create-react-app. I'm not sure about the server type since it's University owned, I just have the access to ftp files into my own reserved directory.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming you are not using hash router.  You can try this instead of browser router, and that could handle the issue.  Also, you could use some sort of back end to resolve this.